# Do you say "a block of milk" or "a block of milk boxes"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> [block](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/block): 4 QUANTITY OF THINGS a quantity of things of the same kind, considered
>   as a single unit block of
>
> New employees receive a block of shares in the firm.
>
> Set aside blocks of time for doing your homework.

Look at the below picture, there are 4 small boxes of milk that were packed into **a block**.

[image]

Do you say "**a block of milk**" or "**a block of milk boxes**"?

For example, *Please bring me the whole block of milk!*

Comment: Assuming that you understand *a block of milk* to be four boxes of milk, then either sentence will do.

Comment: Here in the UK I've only seen fruit juice in **cartons** of that size. I think a number of them sold together are called a **pack** rather than a block.

Comment: @KateBunting, but in the supermarket, they say "4 pack, 6 pack". The "Pack" without "s".  Does it mean "a pack of 4 or 6"? (see the picture in this link https://libertyfoods.ca/milk-cream/50156-milk-2-go-chocolate-6-pack)

Comment: Yes, it does mean that.

Comment: These are often called 'tetra packs' in North America, from the Latin prefix 'tetra-' meaning 'four'.